# Is there a way to prevent transpile Class to constructor?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I have an node.js application uses Flow. To rid of Flow syntax, I used babel:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "flow"],
    "plugins":  [
        "transform-flow-strip-types"
    ]
}
```

It works, but the problem is the using "instanceof" operator. I extended standard error constructor like this:

```
/* @flow */
class BadRequestError extends Error {
    constructor(message:string) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class InvalidRequestBodyError extends Error {
    constructor(message:string) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class UnauthorizedError extends Error {
    constructor(message:string) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class ExpiredResourceError extends Error {
    constructor(message:string) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class InternalServerError extends Error {
    constructor(message:string) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class ResourceNotFoundError extends Error {
    constructor(message:string) {
        super(message);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    BadRequestError,
    InvalidRequestBodyError,
    UnauthorizedError,
    ExpiredResourceError,
    InternalServerError,
    ResourceNotFoundError
};
```

In Node.js, it works. But after transpiled, instanceof doesn't work anymore because Classes transformed to Constructors.

Is there a way to prevent it?

Using babel-cli@6.26.0 and node@8.9.0, and this is the command line am I using:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/babel ./src -d ./dist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by

1. Adding babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend
2. Change the class something like this:

   ```
   class BadRequestError extends Error {
       constructor(message:string) {
       super(message);

           /* $FlowFixMe */
           this.constructor = BadRequestError;
           /* $FlowFixMe */
           this.__proto__ = BadRequestError.prototype;
       }
   }
   ```

Note that follow by [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4485#issuecomment-377962987), it will fixed in Babel 7!

Answer (score 1):

As [Babel `preset-env` documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) states,

> Without any configuration options, babel-preset-env behaves exactly the same as babel-preset-latest (or babel-preset-es2015, babel-preset-es2016, and babel-preset-es2017 together).

This is the reason why ES6 classes are transpiled to regular functions.

This page contains all information regarding using this preset in Node:

> For convenience, you can use "node": "current" to only include the necessary polyfills and transforms for the Node.js version that you use to run Babel

It should be:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "current"
      }
    }, "flow"],
    "plugins":  [
        "transform-flow-strip-types"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks to reply, but well, that wasn't problem. I fixed by adding another plugin and technics someone told.

Comment: Glad you solved it, but this is the real problem here. Since you're already using `env`, that's the way is supposed to be used. It serves to apply only the transforms that are needed in specified environment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I just change the target env to node: 6.9.5, which is my real target platform uses, but Babel still transform classes to Constructors. Followed by this site: https://node.green/, Node supports class from v4.9.1. Why this happens?

Comment: @modernator Yes, classes are supported since 4.0. I cannot replicate this. I specify `"node": "6.9.5"` and it behaves the same way as `"node": "current"` by not transpiling classes. It's Babel CLI 6.18.0 and babel-preset-env 1.6.1. Same here for latest Babel 6, https://babeljs.io/repl/#?code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1qQJ4DtjQEYAoBKRAXyRKA&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=Node-6.9&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2